# ServiceBusClient to read Dead letter message reason

Tags: azureservicebus, dlq

I am creating an instance of ServiceBusClient to create MessageReceiver object. The MessageReceiver gives access to PeekMessageAsync method to peek into the DLQ messages and read the reason and error description.

I want to use the ManagedIdentity to authenticate the azure function. I am not able to authenticate the ServiceBusClient using ManagedIdentity.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few steps required to set up managed identity authentication for accessing Service Bus as outlined in this [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-managed-service-identity). At a high level, here are what you need to do

1. Enable Managed Identity on your Azure Function App
2. Create a Role Assignment for your Function App on the Service Bus resource with the `Azure Service Bus Data Receiver` role
3. In your code, initialize the [`ServiceBusClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusclient?view=azure-dotnet) class with the [`DefaultAzureCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet) or [`ManagedIdentityCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.managedidentitycredential?view=azure-dotnet)

You can refer to [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-msi-servicebus-dotnet) which showcases the same but with App Service.